# ProLiant DL380 G7 Won't Boot

Tags: hp-proliant

I have a ProLiant DL380 G7 server that displays the blinking red status light on the front and both CPU lights are lit up amber.  It will not boot.  I tried to reseat the fans and the memory and that didn't do anything.  I came in the next day and it worked like it should.

This morning I have the same lights lit up and I can't boot the server.  I've searched for the answers about the CPU lights on front being amber but I can't find out what they mean.  Any ideas what it could be?

It's funny it worked for a day or two and quit again. I saw another post on Server Fault but they never posted what fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amber light for the CPU is all related to the processor.

I send this document from HP, which can help a bit, but I would suggest to update the firmware if you ever happen to be able to boot that server again. (Unplug the AC power, let it cooldown a lot, and retry to boot the server after)

The fact both CPU light started to blink at the same time and it worked a bit in between make me think it's maybe a motherboard issue, bad capacitor, etc.. that make the BIOS check fail.

[image]

Comment: The cpu lights are steady amber.  I reset everything and put a new cmos battery in it and it is up again but I can't trust it yet.  I will check to see it there is any firmware updates for any of the hardware.  Thanks for the meaning of the lights, I couldn't find that online.  Thanks for the help.